# cumulative return of savings plan with deposits in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, finance, cumsum

I am trying to calculate a monthly savings plan using financial time series with python pandas.

I need to calculate the cumulative return given the percent changes in the time series BUT also take into account monthly deposits.

The standard way to calculate the cumulative return from a dataframe is:

```
df['cum_ret'] = (1 + df.monthly_rets).cumprod() - 1
```

But now, I have monthly deposits, say, each month 100$ are saved and added to the portfolio.

How do I calculate the final value of the portfolio?

I think the answer is to  loop over the dataframe and summ the cumulative return from i to n where i increases in the loop..

But how do I do that?

Any help is appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Some sample inputs and preferred output would help. Please see: creating a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer without some more of the inputs and outputs. But have you tried:

```
df['cum_ret'].sum()
```